# OpenGL 4.5 not writing integer renderbuffer

Tags: c++, opengl, integer, glsl, glm-math

(OGL 4.5 on win10 with nVidia GPU).

I am trying to render labeled triangles as a single channel image with unsigned int pixels  but apparently the frag shader is not writing to the framebuffer.  I have eliminated every cause I can think of.

- OGL reports that my chosen internal format, GL_R32UI, is supported, color renderable, framebuffer renderable and valid for read_pixels, and that the framebuffer is complete;
- I'm using the simplest possible render call, namely glDrawArrays, with an array of 2D vertex coordinates and an array of per-vertex int labels bound to the shader program;
- I have disabled depth, scissor and stencil tests (anyhow my fbo has only a color attachment) and face culling;
- I *think* I'm projecting the vertices into clip space right. Coordinates are on the same pixel grid used for output, so I'm generated the mvp matrix like this:

  ```
  glm::mat4 mvp = glm::ortho(
      0.f, float(width),
      0.f, float(height),
      0.5f, 1.5f
  );
  ```

  and setting the z coordinate to 1.0 in the vertex shader.  Whose code is

  ```c
  "#version 450\n"
  "uniform mat4 MVP;\n"
  "in vec2 vPos;\n"
  "in unsigned int Tdx;\n"
  "out flat unsigned int tid;\n"
  "void main()\n"
  "{\n"
  "    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vPos, 1.0, 1.0);\n"
  "    tid = Tdx;\n"
  "}\n";
  ```

  The frag shader just outputs a copy of tid:

  ```c
  "#version 450\n"
  "in flat unsigned int tid;\n"
  "out unsigned int color;\n"
  "void main()\n"
  "{\n"
  "   color = tid;\n"
  "}\n";
  ```

`glReadPixels()` returns whatever I clear the framebuffer to, but never what I have tried to draw.
Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The z-axis is the cross product of the x-axis and the y-axis. In the view space, the z-axis therefore points out of the view.

[image]

In your case, z must therefore be -1:

<s>`gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vPos, 1.0, 1.0);`</s>

```c
gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vPos, -1.0, 1.0);
```